# Weekending date in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I have a view in which I need to show the weekending date for each row. I have used the following query:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT [Delivery Date], [Delivery Method], [Order Total], YEAR([Delivery Date]) AS Year, DATEADD(d, 7 - DATEPART(dw, [Delivery Date]), [Delivery Date]) 
                      AS WeekEnd
FROM         dbo.salesdata
ORDER BY [Delivery Date] DESC
```

Works well except that the Weekend date is based on Sunday being the first day of the week and not Monday which is standard in NZ.

I have looked around and the only option that looks like it would work is to set the DATEFIRST however you can't to that in a view.

Please help!

Comment: Which date are you expecting to see if 'Delivery Date' is today (2015-03-09)?

Comment: I would expect to see the 15th (2015-03-15). if delivery date is 2015-03-08 then I wold expect to see 2015-03-08.

Comment: Edge case, what value should you see if its 2015-03-08?  Does it move to the next week?

Comment: See previous comment (sorry edited while you were replying)

Comment: Our week runs from Monday to Sunday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to move forward one day but not be tripped by the start of week.  The key here is the modulus '%' which rolls the adjusted days back to the beginning. If your week started on a Wednesday, you'd simply replace '+ 1' with '+ 3' and everything would work.

```
DATEADD(d, (7 - DATEPART(dw, [Delivery Date]) + 1) % 7, [Delivery Date]) AS WeekEnd

SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    [Delivery Date],
    [Delivery Method],
    [Order Total],
    YEAR([Delivery Date]) AS Year,
    DATEADD(d, (7 - DATEPART(dw, [Delivery Date]) + 1) % 7, [Delivery Date]) AS WeekEnd
FROM dbo.salesdata
ORDER BY [Delivery Date] DESC
```